# Which one of the following codes is faster in excecution?

Tags: c, performance, execution-time

Basically which one of the Codes will return 0, faster ?

// if the answer is "the same" because the code is simple than imagine a more complex code variant written in the same way but with more code.

Code 1:

```
int a = 0;

if(a == 1){ 
    return 1;
}else{
    return 0;
}
```

Code 2:

```
int a = 0;

if(a == 1){ 
    return 1;
}
return 0;
```

Comment: Is this some kind of quiz? Just benchmark yourself.

Comment: Generate (optimized) assembly and look for yourself if there is any difference.

Comment: They will probably have the same performance, no matter how simple or complex the code is. That's because both snippets are equivalent and will likely compile down to the same code.

Comment: Assuming the compiler actually generates different code for the two (which it probably won't), the difference will not be measurable.

Comment: They are basically the same. I don't think there will be a difference

Comment: how much faster you are expecting?!!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There will be no difference in the compiler generated code. The `else` is unnecessary but may be written for clarity.